# How to record mic and speakers in one buffer and/or sound file

Tags: delphi, directx

The idea is that one would have a conference using a headset and I have to record conversation entirely(what BOTH sides are saying) at a reasonable quality, the restrictions for components/units are:

- must be compatible(or at least nearly) with Delphi 2010
- if any components involved must be shipped with Delphi 2010 or to be open source

I was thinking about using Direct X but I haven't found a example.

Note: that recording desktop + sound(mic and speakers) would be even better.

If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice Recording/Saving in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441613/voice-recording-saving-in-delphi)

Comment: If you allow for non-standard non-open-source, then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499669/how-to-record-anything-from-soundcards

Comment: @Jeroen It's NOT duplicate, in the title it's written "mic and speakers" basically a mix between those two -- I saw no reason in writing the same thing as in title twice, obviously I was wrong.

Comment: No offence, but I still think it is a *possible* duplicate, my answer explains why.

Comment: none taken, but recording "microphone and speaker sound" into one buffer and/or file is not the same thing as recording the microphone only, it imposes some workarounds, I've commented on your answer and edited the question(-"BOTH"- sides of the conversations needs to be recorded)

Comment: @Jeroen - I don't think this is a duplicate, there's no mixing in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [record the "Stereo Mix" just like a Microphone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfdzx7mr51Y), so any Delphi recording answer will suffice.

*Edit:*
[This thread on the Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/e61f3bc8-b7a2-47b9-8884-4c0c7bea048b) talks about a virtual audio driver that might do the trick on Windows XP.

--jeroen

Comment: this is a possible solution, but from what I've read, some sound cards might not have "stereo mix" which imposes a issue, furthermore I've tried that and the speaker sound volume is bad when played back...

Comment: @Dorin this is the best you can do; alternatives (like redirecting the stereo output cable through splitters in the mic socket) are even worse.

Comment: @Dorin - From what I understand, if the audio hardware/driver does not support it, "stereo-mix" will not be available. In this case there's nothing you can do unless the OS is Vista+, which can do software loopback-recording. There's sample code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx), maybe you can convert it..

Answer (score 1):

You might try the audio library at:  http://www.un4seen.com/

The "BASS" DLLs work fine with Windows Xp.  They are free for non-commercial use though not open source but mentioned as it still might fulfill your requirements.   There are issues that preclude its use for recording functions on some PCs where the recording function is disabled.  You have to establish whether the dlls work with Delphi 2010.  It works very well with Delphi 2007.

Comment: @Jeroen    Yes, you can record the "Stero Mix" just like a microphone, but not on all Windows PC.  The Stereo Mix is disabled on a large number of PCs produced during a period when the recording industry was threating lawsuits.  Dorin is correct, some audio cards, especially some in laptops do not support stereo mix.

Comment: additionally, it is possible to record "anything" that goes through an audio card (unless the card is built with "restrictions")... whether it is output to speakers, mic, line in, line out etc.   ...and yes, using splitters on cables is not a satisfactory solution because of the audio quality.

Comment: I'm involved with quite a bit of ASIO software development, there such things are not an issue at all. But only few audio cards support ASIO, and the generic ASIO4ALL driver needs quite a bit of CPU to do its work.

Comment: I just recorded a Skype conversation, essentially using the Delphi example code that comes with the bass.dll. I use Xp so Stereo Mix is available. Compiled it in Delphi 2007. The company's did not start imposing hardware/driver "limitations" until about the issuing of Vista. The code won't work with my son's Win7 32 bit because there is no Stereo Mix available with the driver for his Gateway laptop. Dorin appears to be attempting to duplicate software like Skype or IP-Sound that already can do the "conversation" or "conference" part of his request.

Comment: @SteveJG I am not trying to replicate any software, the idea is that we have a lot of people doing their work using a software application that does not support conference recording on client's PC, they do not expose any API's(my personal opinion is that they don't have...) so I need to achieve this task as best and elegant as possible, however recording from stereomix raises quality concerns that's the whole point of my question, I thought that until now someone else have already achieved a better solution or at least have a work-around for this issue.

Comment: @Dorin OK. Tools like the bass.dll help you record at different "quality" settings and allow setting the "quality" in the coding. You can not (easily) improve the quality of what appears in the audio card from the external sources. How you save the audio makes a difference(*.wav, mp3 etc.). You can record at 8bit, 16, 32 bit, in stereo or mono, select number of channels and sampling rates. The 'quality' you pick affects the size of the recorded file. The 'quality' is also affected by the characteristics of the microphone used in the 'chats' and the quality of the audio cards. Bass uses DirectX